# formatting only in minutes in excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am using excel 2007.I need help in formating cells to display only minutes.
Suppose if the actual duration is 30 seconds,it should show .5

Comment: please add some more detail, your question is very vague.

for example what exactly are you putting in the cell?

Comment: @AasimAzam I want o convert an existing date time column to show only minutes.all the hours and seconds should get converted to minutes.for example 1 hr should show 60 min and 30 sec should show 0.5 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to multiply your time value by **1440** (the number of minutes in a day), so if A1 contains 5:20 then use this formula in B1 to get 320

`=A1*1440`

This solution will work for any time value, even values over 24 hours, e.g. converts 33:20 to 2000

Edit: I note you mention "formatting" - you could custom format A1 as [m] (you need to include the square brackets) which would also display 320 or 2000 in my examples without need for a formula in another cell.......but that will only display an integer so you can't use that to get 0.5 for 30 seconds

Answer (score 1):

=(HOUR(A1))*60+MINUTE(A1)+ IF(SECOND(A1)>30, INT(1+ SECOND(A1)/60), SECOND(A1)/60)